# How can I manually allow access to a visitor for my private website?

Tags: ios, security, push-notification

I want to host my own Linktree Open-Source alternative project on my own domain for sharing my information. It will include the following:

- Instagram
- Linkedin
- **Personal vCard (Phone number included)** -> For this URL, which can redirect to another subdomain that I control, I want to manually approve access for anyone that requests it.

The question is: **Are you aware of any open-source solution that would allow the user visiting my vCard subdomain to enter his name and click on "Request access" and that would send me a notification on my iPhone (like the Gmail login confirmation) so that I can allow or disallow access?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is to put all your resources on the closed network. And build your VPN server.

And if your friends want to look at your resource, just give them a VPN account.

Then if you want `enter his name and click on "Request access"`, I think this is a big system. you must learn a lot about system development.